# How to make new string xml in value folder and how to access its content in layout xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I want to make new xml file in my value folder same as string.xml.
So in my app I make new xml file in value folder with name `basic.xml` and this xml contain string content like this:

basic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World</string>
</resources>
```

But when I try to access this `basic.xml` in my  `main_activity.xml` layout file in layout folder, then I can't be able to access basic.xml and its content.
main_activity.xml

[image: mainactivity]

(Note - I am using eclipse.)

So how to make new string.xml like file in value folder properly and how to access it layout xml file. ?

Comment: Did you found `@string/hello`?

Comment: @PratikButani But suppose if i also have one "hello" string attribute in string.xml and one in basic.xml then which one it will access???

Comment: How you want to make difference?

Comment: I want to say that .........  in my basic.xml i have string attribute like this `<string name="hello">Hello World</string>` and in string.xml  string attribute like this `<string name="hello">Say hello to pratik</string>` . Now when I try to access my basic.xml like  @string/hello in my layout file then it give me output `Hello World`.  means its not access basic.xml. So how can basic.xml content when string attribute name `hello` is same in both xml files ???????????

Comment: @DevendraDagur any solution yet???